# ReadAsAsync calling a WebAPI not reconstituting json to class

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am making a call to a WebAPI that returns some Content from a db via JSON. The content is visible in the JSON (viewed using Fiddler) but when I try to put the response data back into a class all the values are null in the class.

This used to work but now fails. I suspect that I may not be using the GetAsync and ReadAsAsync correctly.

**new note**
This is one example but there are several other similar calls that cause the same issue.

Any thoughts why this has stopped working? and what would be the correct way to fix it?

The Class:

```
 public class ContentElement : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
}
```

The Code:

```
 public static List<ContentElement> GetContent(int siteId)
    {
        var contentElements = new List<ContentElement>();
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalValues.APIUri);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            AddAuthenticationHeader(client);
            var result = client.GetAsync("api/Content/GetContent/" + (object)siteId).Result;
            if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                contentElements.AddRange((IEnumerable<ContentElement>)result.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<ContentElement>>().Result);
            }
        }
        return contentElements;
    }
```

The JSON:

```
[{"PageId":1,"LanguageCode":"en","ContentId":5,"PageName":"Greeting",
"Content":"Content goes here","DisplayOrder":1,"Image":null,"ContentType":"Text"}]
```

Comment: any particular reason you are using async without awaits

Comment: @MrinalKamboj He doesn't need to use await here because he is using .Result at the end of the  async call. Using .Result will wait for the task to be completed just like await does.

Comment: Can we see an example of the JSON being returned?

Comment: @Alok because of the .Result at the end of the Async call as noted by deruitda

Comment: @deruitda Json has been added

Comment: see my answer below, I believe adding those two extra properties will solve this issue.

Comment: @deruitda i missed out the `Result` in the end on the mobile, but invariably it is always a good idea to use the `await` with async calls, using Result on a async call is always a bad idea and its better to make the call Synchronous

Comment: You are making all the Async calls in a Sync manner, which will always a bad idea, use them using `Async - Await` to achieve the objective, that's most efficient

Comment: There's no method `ReadAsAsync<..>` in the HttpContent, checkout MS docs, [HttpContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpcontent?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your json has "Image" and"ContentType" properties, but your class does not. Add these as properties to your class. .NET cannot deserialize the json in your class because it does not have the EXACT same properties as the class.

```
 public class ContentElement : ICloneable
{
    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
    public int PageId { get; set; }
    public string LanguageCode { get; set; }
    public int ContentId { get; set; }
    public string PageName { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; } //not sure what type this should be
    public string ContentType { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT** A workaround fix for this is to use Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the json instead of using the .NET function.

```
contentElements.AddRange((IEnumerable<ContentElement>)JsonConvert.Deserialize<IEnumerable<ContentElement>>(result.Content));
```

Comment: I've added those two fields in but still not working as it used to.  Prior to the issue starting I had the same classes and JSON without those fields.

Comment: I do have Newtonsoft.Json as part of the project. Do you think an update to that library may have started causing the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure about that. ReadAsAsync is part of the .NET Framework, not Newtonsoft.Json. If you do have Newtonsoft.Json you could try using that to deserialize your json. Try using this instead: contentElements.AddRange((IEnumerable<ContentElement>)JsonConvert.Deserialize<IEnumerable<ContentElement>>(result.Content));

Comment: you last comment helped.  I used Json.ConvertObject and got it to work as needed/expected. My biggest question at this point is why did it stop working? I guess a mystery I'll have to dig in to someday..... maybe

Comment: Is this a .NET Framework app or .NET core? And what version?

Comment: First part of your answer is incorrect, since difference in schema doesn't impact Json serialization / deserialization, it works with the available fields. In second part you are deserializing the `HttpContent`, when ideally this code shall call `ReadAsStringAsync` using `await`, which shall be de-serialized, that's the correct way as per Microsoft examples, since deserializing `HttpContent` may deprecate in the future

Comment: I've changed everything to use Newtonsoft and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public async static Task<List<ContentElement>> GetContent(int siteId)
        {
            var contentElements = new List<ContentElement>();
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(GlobalValues.APIUri);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                AddAuthenticationHeader(client);
                var result =await client.GetAsync("api/Content/GetContent/" + (object)siteId);
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    contentElements.AddRange((IEnumerable<ContentElement>)result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync<List<ContentElement>>());
                }
            }
            return contentElements;
        }
```

make the method async and use await like this

Comment: as noted in the comments, this is not causing the issue. He is using .Result at the end of his async call which will wait for the task to be completed before moving forward with the execution, which is exactly what await does.

Comment: @deruitda Incorrect `Result` is not a direct replacement of `Async-Await`, there's a huge difference between Async and Sync processing of data, Async processing is much more scalable and in this case there are no synchronous methods exposed on the HttpContent

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Right, sorry I didn't mean to make it sound like they did the same thing, I meant that functionally it will produce the same result.